# How to selectively render directive with same name from different module

Tags: angularjs

If I have two module ---

```
angular.module('moduleA', []).directive('foo', /* ... */);
angular.module('moduleB', []).directive('foo', /* ... */);
```

and main angular app,

```
angular.module('app', ['moduleA', 'moduleB']);
```

let's say in this app, i want to select which module's directive to use

```
<div ng-app="app">
  <foo use="moduleA"><!-- Use foo directive from module A --></foo>
  <foo use="moduleB"><!-- Use foo directive from module B --></foo>
</div>
```

Is it possible to accomplish something along this line?

Answer (score 0):

Instead of `ng-app`, use `ng-modules="moduleA, moduleB"`.
Put `ng-app` in html tag